# Using a previously made animation and trying to move 1 object in all keyframes

Tags: animation

I'm using an already existing animation in StoneHearth because I want it to be similar in style to the original.

What I'm trying to do is basically take this walking animation where a guy is holding two swords in his hands, and I want to move the 'offhand sword' away from his hand and onto his side because I'm going to replace the model with a sheath. I can do this for one keyframe but then the other 192 keyframes move it back to his hand. So I'm wondering if there is a way for me to move the object to his side and then make it attached there for the rest of the key frames.

Comment: Can you delete the extra keyframes that you don't need? That's probably easier than going in and manually changing them all.

Comment: You may want to post the .blend file if people are having difficulty answering your question in a satisfactory way.